# Filtering the divs before they are displayed i.e. before ajax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I m having some 1000 of records which i want to display in divs.i am displaying them in bundles of 20.And when you scroll to bottom loads next 20 records.
On the left hand side i have kept some filters(javascript checkboxes) which will show/hide div s on basis of checked value.the first records which are there on the screen are filtered with those checkboxes.But when i scroll and load new 20 records in success function of my ajax call,that checkbox which are selected or filtering condition of div is not working for those div s.Those new Records are displayed as it is,without any filteration.
I m able to filter the records in present page but if u check the checkbox and then scroll to bottom and load new records.Those records are not getting filtered on scrolling.

How to do the filteration for ajax loading content??
Please help on this....

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="1000" data-location="US">Peter</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="1200" data-location="Mexico">Willy</div><br />

    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="2000" data-location="US">Peter</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="800" data-location="Mexico">Peter</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="1300" data-location="Mexico">Willy</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="800" data-location="US">Willy</div><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="name" id="Peter">Peter
    <input type="checkbox" class="name" id="Willy">Willy
    <input type="checkbox" class="location" id="US">US
    <input type="checkbox" class="location" id="Mexico">Mexico
```

Following is my checkbox filtering logic

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input.name").prop("checked", true).change(function (e) {
        $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
    });
    $("input.location").prop("checked", true).change(function (e) {
        $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
    });

    $("input[name=range]").change(function (e) {
        var toggle = this.checked;
        var range = this.value.split('-');
        var rangeFrom = parseInt(range[0]);
        var rangeTo = parseInt(range[1]);
        $(".content[data-price]").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var nameActive = $("#" + $this.data("name")).prop("checked");
//            var locationActive = $("#" + $this.data("location")).prop("checked");
            var price = parseFloat($this.data('price'));




            $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo 
                    && nameActive);
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Below is my try for calling ajax and retrieving div s

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page=1;
     <%String name1=(String)session.getAttribute("name");%> 
    var name2="<%=name1%>";
    $(window).scroll(function(e) 
            {if ($(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
            {page++;


            $.ajax({    type : "Get",
                        url : "Someservlet",                        
                        datatype : "JSON",
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        data : {pagenumber : page,
                        Pname : name2},

                        success : function(data) {

                            var data1 = data[0],

                            var len = data1.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                                        var name = "<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Peter" +"</div>"+"<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Willy" +"</div>";



                                $(name).appendTo("#prod");





                            }



                    }


                    });

        }
    });

});

                    </script>
```

Please help on this..

Comment: Post some code so we can help.

Comment: look up .on in jquery - this is the best help we can give without some code!

Comment: @BramVanroy I was about to ask the same.

Comment: i have updated the code .please help getting scrolled elements filterd.

Comment: @Bram -as u told.i posted the code.please help guysss.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `on` and `off` events. like :

```
$(document).off('change',"input.name:checked").off('change',"input.name:checked",function (e) {
            $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
        });
       $(document).off('change',"input.location:checked").off('change',"input.location:checked",function(e) {
            $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
        });

        $(document).off('change',"input[name = 'range']:checked").off('change',"input[name = 'range'],function(e){ 
            var toggle = this.checked;
            var range = this.value.split('-');
            var rangeFrom = parseInt(range[0]);
            var rangeTo = parseInt(range[1]);
            $(".content[data-price]").each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var nameActive = $("#" + $this.data("name")).prop("checked");
    //            var locationActive = $("#" + $this.data("location")).prop("checked");
                var price = parseFloat($this.data('price'));




                $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo 
                        && nameActive);
            });
        });
```

Comment: what does document.off does?and hw will this code work?it will be a lot helpful if you can explain above code

Comment: this code will unbind the event on element and then bind a event on the new element generated. you can see this on the site of jquery. this work as die live of earlier jquery. see http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page=1;
     <%String name1=(String)session.getAttribute("name");%> 
    var name2="<%=name1%>";
    $(window).scroll(function(e) 
            {if ($(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
            {page++;
            checkbox();

            $.ajax({    type : "Get",
                        url : "Someservlet",                        
                        datatype : "JSON",
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        data : {pagenumber : page,
                        Pname : name2},

                        success : function(data) {

                            var data1 = data[0],

                            var len = data1.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                                        var name = "<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Peter" +"</div>"+"<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Willy" +"</div>";



                                $(name).appendTo("#prod");





                            }



                    }


                    });

        }
    });

});
function checkBox(){

    alert("check");
    var a=$("input.name]");
    var name="";
    var location="";

     $("#prod >div").hide();

       if($(a).is(":checked")) {
           alert("brand checked");
        $('#prod >div').hide();
            name=$(this).attr('id');       
        displaydivs(name,location);
       }
   else{ brand=""
        displaydivs(name,location);
        }

}

    function displaydivs(name,location)
    {
    if(name!="" & location!=""){ 

         $("#prod >div[data-location="+location+"][data-name="+name+"]").show();

         }
         else if(name!="" & location==""){ 

         $("#prod >div[data-name="+name+"]").show();
         }
         else if(name=="" & location!=""){

         $("#prod >div[data-location="+name+"]").show();
         }
         }






                        </script>
```

Request you to please check Ehsan,

Comment: after appending html in prod you can do the checkbox checking thing

Comment: k.You mean to say i should call checkbox function after the line where i m appending??and is rest of the thing fyn?

Comment: Ya.it worked.but the only problem is when i m scrolling the id which it is picking,its only Peter,even if i check willy also.its taking ist id only in the row..If i check willy that is second one.still it filters the scrolling records with Peter..Please sought out this issue sir.

Comment: can you post this checkbox function and you html in a jsfiddle, it will be easy to diagnose the issue

Comment: and you need to call this method after appending html of ajax call, right after $(name).appendTo("#prod");

Comment: it was working in my pc.but somehow not able to work in fiddle.fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/5qBTh/ please have a look sir

Comment: I saw you need to write checkbox change event to make it working I am not on sytstem currentrly updting you from my cell, I will update your fiddle when I come on pc

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-Please surely Do.otherwise tell me what to change?or tell me ur email id,will remind u once fr it.As its quite urgent fr me.Please Brother..

Comment: LOL i will do it, i come on So everyday

Comment: and let me know, if you got how to do it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-Thanks man.one small help sir in this code.When i m checking one option out of peter and willy,its displaying div s related to them,like i selected peter,it displayed peter contents,but if i selected willy also while peter is selected it hides the peter contens and displays only willy where as both contents should come if both are checked...Please help sir on this...

Comment: Give it a try yourself also,  I will check it when I will come on my system

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-i tried sir. http://jsfiddle.net/Y95ku/. This is my fiddle trying link.i tried for above problem issue tht i mentioned in previous comment,but no luck man...PLease help me out man from this problem..

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-Please have a look at the jsfiddle code sir.please